Unable to Apply Custom Style from Word Template using bookdown::word_document2 in R
I'm trying to output a Word document using bookdown::word_document2 in R, and I have set up a Word template with a custom style named "mycap" in the file mytemplate.docx. My goal is to apply this "mycap" style to the captions of figures and tables in the Word document.
However, for some reason, the custom style does not seem to be applied to the captions as expected. I am not sure where the problem lies. I upload my template.docx to my github (https://github.com/lizhiwei1994/data/blob/main/mytemplate.docx), and you can download it, Below is the code I am using:
---
title: "Example Document"
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    reference_docx: "mytemplate.docx"  
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(officedown)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  fig.cap.style = "mycap",
  tab.cap.style = 'mycap'
  )
```

```{r boxplot1, fig.cap="Boxplot", fig.cap.style="mycap", out.width='50%'}
boxplot(1:10)
```

```{r table1, tab.cap.style = 'mycap'}
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars, 5))
ft <- set_caption(ft, 
                  caption = "Table title",
                  style = "mycap")
ft
```

This is Figure\@ref(fig:boxplot1);
This is Table\@ref(tab:table1).




The current word output is as follows:


fig.cap.style and tab.cap.style are options defined in officedown which require officedown::rdocx_document as the output format. They will have no effect in bookdown::word_document2. And I can only guess that the style you set via set_caption is overridden by the bookdown::word_document2 defaults. When you require bookdown::word_document2 then I would suggest to render your document once. Then use the rendered document as reference docx where you customize the styles applied for the captions to your needs.
